# Loop over json file and append

Tags: python, json

I know this question might irritate the expert but I hope you can have patience with a beginner.

I am trying to loop over multiple json file and format them as array object and save all those json file into a new json file. I need to basically merge all the files into one so I can have a accurate calculation of the unique ID.

so far I have this:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("./"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.json'):
            to_queue = []
            with open(file, "r+") as f:
                print(file)
                old = f.read()
                f.seek(0)  # rewind
                # save to the old string after replace
                new = old.replace('}{', '},{')
                f.write(new)
                tmps = '[' + str(new) + ']'
                json_string = json.loads(tmps)
                for key in json_string:
                    to_queue.append(key)
                f.close
            with open('update.json', 'a') as file:
                json.dump(json_string, file, indent=2)
            with open('update.json') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                users = set(item.get('userID') for item in data)
                print(len(users))
                # print(users
```

It loops over every single files, format it and save it to `update.json` which after being saved, I can count the unique `UserID` present in the update.json.

This is the idea, but when I run the code I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 17821 column 2 (char 501079)
```

As I mentioned I am a total beginner and I feel embarrassed to ask question that might be super easy for somebody else, I just hope somebody can kindly help me to understand how to go over this problem and why it happens.

Thank you so much

UPDATE:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("./"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.json'):
            to_queue = []
            newdictionary = {}
            with open(file, "r+") as f:
                print(file)
                old = f.read()
                f.seek(0)  # rewind
                # save to the old string after replace
                new = old.replace('}{', '},{')
                f.write(new)
                tmps = '[' + str(new) + ']'
                json_string = json.loads(tmps)
                for key in json_string:
                    to_queue.append(key)
                    newdictionary.update(key)
                f.close
            for key in newdictionary:
                with open('update.json', 'a') as file:
                    json.dump(key, file, indent=2)
            with open('update.json') as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                users = set(item.get('userID') for item in data)
                print(len(users))
```

This is the latest code error using buran code, which I really thank for his help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "format.py", line 40, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 194 (char 193)
```

this is the raw content of the json files:

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-07-30T20:28:25.769Z","name":"","deviceAction":""},{"@timestamp":"2021-07-30T20:29:10.812Z","name":"","deviceAction":""}
```

In my previous code I had the formatting in place to convert them into an array. Some files looks like this, bot other have extra fields like this.

```
 {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "destinationUserName": "",
    "message": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "destinationUserName": "",
    "message": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "destinationUserName": "",
    "message": "",
    "name": ""
  },
  {
    "@timestamp": "",
    "userID": "",
    "name": "",
    "sourceUserName": "",
    "deviceAction": ""
  }
```

Comment: loop through every file, open, parse json. assign variable to empty dictionary, then use the update (`dictionary.update`) method to add them all together

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer. I am not sure I get exactly how to approach this. I updated my code, but I am getting the same error

Comment: Stop trying to manually construct JSON strings. **Deserialize into a Python data structure*. Add that to a list. When done, serialize that whole list to a new JSON.

Comment: I am using buran code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json


# loop over files recursively and store dicts from each file in a list

all_data = []
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk("./"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.json'):
            with open(file, "r") as f:
                # files are not valid json and need some pre-processing        
                raw_data = f.read()
                try:
                    data = json.loads(f'[{raw_data.replace("}{", "},{")}]') # some files have missing comma between objects
                    all_data.extend(data)
                except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                    print(f'Error with file {file}')


# write all data to new file
with open('all_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(all_data, f, indent=4)

users = set(item.get('userID') for item in all_data)
print(f'Number of users: {len(users)}')


# or read the file and count all unique users
with open('all_data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    users = set(item.get('userID') for item in data)
    print(f'Number of users: {len(users)}')
```

Alternatively, instead of reading `all_data.json` at the end, you can update can create empty set `users` in the begining and update it with unique users in every file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I see the logic and the simplicity of the code, but yet it is giving me the exact same error. Extra data

Comment: what I meant is that the nature of the error is still `Extra Data` but now is happens right at the beginning and is not even creating the json file. I will update my post with the full error

Comment: There error point to line 40..which is ` data = json.load(f)`

Comment: I am so frustrated. Adding the try and except it just skips all the files :(

Comment: I just updated my post with the raw json files I have. In my previous code I used to manipulate the content to add `[ ]` to the json file

Comment: This worked on half way. Maybe I spot the error in the file that has been skipped. Al the file skipped are structured like this 
`{"deviceAction":"","userID":"w10-840g7$","name":"","sourceUserName":"","@timestamp":"2021-09-06T00:00:35.430Z"}{"deviceAction":"","userID":"","name":"","sourceUserName":"","@timestamp":"2021-09-06T00:00:35.431Z"}`` Which basically they don't have the `,` between the `{ }` could be this the error why they get skipped?

Comment: Yes. Assuming there are no other strings like this `}{`, I added replace to add comma - `},{`

Comment: And that worked. omg thank you thank you thank you. Can I just ask you another question. This counts the unique userID, is there a way how I can save those users in a external file? I hope I am not asking too much

Comment: you can write set `users` to file any way you want. And don't forget there is one None in users because you have dicts without key userID

Comment: I deleted my comments from this long chain